# php recursive include function in 2 file with different path

Tags: php, include

Hi all I've a problem with include function in php:

I have 4 file:

```
dir1/file1.php
dir4/dir2/file2.php
dir3/file3.php
dir3/file4.php
```

In file1.php I have:

```
include_once('../dir3/file3.php');
```

In file3.php I have:

```
required('../dir3/file4.php');
```

In file2.php I want write:

```
include_once('../../dir3/file3.php');
```

but the required function in file3 doesn't work because the path of file4 must be

```
../../dir3/file4.php
```

and not

```
../dir3/file4.php
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you figured it out yourself, you can post a answer if you want, don't write it in the question. (Added a answer, maybe it solves your problem too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use only dot (.) before your filename which will find that file from root of dir..for eg `./dir3/file4.php` but it increase the overhead..Another way is to use

```
$base = __DIR__ . '/../';

require_once $base.'_include/file1.php';
```

Comment: with include_once('./dir3/file3.php'); in file1.php not work.
And I want use the php application in window e linux system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling file3 from file2 you will have to go back 2 directories. The best way is using the full path like :

```
home/mysite/public_html/dir3/file3.php
```

It maybe (is) troublesome but good uptill some level.
Edit: **DIR** and rest is also handy, depending on your need

Comment: sorry but the path can change with different OS. I want a portable php application.

Answer (score 0):

**I FIX it with:**

In file1.php I have:

```
$path = '..';    
include_once($path.'/dir3/file3.php');
```

In file3.php I have:

```
required($path.'/dir3/file4.php');
```

In file2.php I want write:

```
$path = '../..'
include_once($path.'/dir3/file3.php');
```

**This work for me.**